# translate3d(0,0,200px) -> what will be the width?

Tags: css, translate3d

consider the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/s4Ppf/

The initial width of #child is 100px. Now, after translating it 200px into the z-direction is it possible to compute what the width will be ? instead of doing something like

```
$('#child').width() ;
```

thanks!